# document.title sent using json with symbols on IE 11, not on other browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am using `document.title` to send the title over using JSON. However, in IE it recognized only the English characters. How can I fix this? Here is my current code.

```
function browsing() {
  $.getJSON("handler.php?type=browsing&callback=?&url=" + document.location.pathname + "&page=" + document.title);
}
```

Here is the output of my `browsing` function.

[image: document.title output]

Comment: Have you used `<meta charset='UTF-8'/>`?

Comment: @DavidArchibald yes of course

Comment: Can you create a [Minimal, Verifiable, Complete Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please?

Comment: @SamOnela I have updated my question with the exact json I am using. thank you

Comment: Does this [github](https://github.com/CSS-Tricks/AnythingSlider/issues/514) thread help, if so I'll make an answer(It applies to a different IE version and could be useless).

Comment: @DavidArchibald i don't think so. I have updated my question with what I get

Comment: use an object so it will get urlencoded. You never answered what charset is set in page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
$.getJSON("handler.php", {
    type: 'browsing',
    callback:'?',
    url: document.location.pathname,
    page: document.title
});
```

This should take care of encoding the text correctly for URL usage.